# Texture Paint Not Updating Automatically

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, texture-painting

I am texture painting over a 3d Model. When I fist began this process, I could paint in the material view, then click over to render view to see how everything was looking with cycles. Now ever since I saved the texture paint image file (to make sure I don't loose my progress) the painting does not show up automatically when I switch to cycles render view. I can still see the paint as I am painting in Material view, but when I tab over to render view it is not there, until I go over to my image editor and manually save the image texture again. It used to update automatically. Now I have to manually save the texture every time I want to check out my progress in rendered view. Not a huge deal but very annoying. Any ideas?

Blender version 4.02

Comment: I think that the image texture doesn't refresh instantly in Rendered preview in Cycles, you need to switch to Material preview then switch back

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: I did some more searching and this seems to be a known bug with blender. Hopefully it gets fixed, but its been going on for years apparently.